# Comparing arrays in a function with null values

Tags: java, arrays, function, null

I'm currently learning about function and have the given task:

*"Write a function eqarr, which takes two int-arrays as arguments and returns true, if they are equal, and false otherwise; your function should return a value in every case (even if the arrays are null)"*

I'm having issues with checking if an array is null. I'm getting the arrays to check if the equal against one another, but with null it's a different issue. Whenever i try and check if a[i] is equal to null `a[i] == null`, i get this error `error: bad operand types for binary operator '=='`.

We can't use existing functions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

```
public class Week8Q5 {

  public static boolean eqarr(int[] a, int[] b) {

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

      if (a[i] != b[i])
        return false;

    }
    return true;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    int[] b = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    System.out.println(eqarr(a, b));

  }
}
```

Comment: perform these checks before the loop  `if (a == null && b == null) return true;
        if (a == null || b == null) return false;
        if (a.length != b.length) return false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `a[i]` you are accessing an *element* of your array. Since that array is defined as `int[]` (i.e. an array of *[primitive int values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)*) it will never be `null`.

But your current implementation will fail if `a` itself is `null`, so you are supposed to check that:

```
public static boolean eqarr(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a == null || b == null) {
        // return appropriate value
    }
}
```

Where "appropriate" is up to you. Usually one would expect the method to return `false` if one of the arrays is `null` and the other isn't and `true` it both are `null`.

Note that you have another issue with your code. As a hint: Try to compare two arrays with different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an array `arr` is `null` using the condition `arr == null`.

You can perform the following checks in sequence to solve the exercise:

- Return `false` if one of the arrays is `null` and the other is not.
- Return `true` if both arrays are `null`.
- Return `false` if the length of the arrays are different.
- Return `false` if any of the elements are different.
- Return `true` if you have reached this point (have not returned from any of the earlier checks).

Answer (score 0):

The question says explicitly that you should return a value if the arrays are null and not the values they are containing. The primitive type int can't be null anyway.

Try something like:

```
public static boolean eqarr(int[] a, int[] b) {

        if (a == null && b == null) {
            return true;
        }

        if(!(a == null || b == null)) {

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

                if (a[i] != b[i])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without giving away too much, `a[i]` denotes the `i`th element of your array and `a` denotes the array itself.

You can only compare (e.g. `!=` and `==`) values of compatible data types. The error message derives from an attempt to compare values of incompatible data types.